# Spring MVC multiple select for a list in a table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, html-table, multiple-select

I am having a problem with persisting data from a multiple select in an HTML table. Here are the details:
Technologies used:
Spring 4.0.5, Hibernate 4.3.5, MySQL 5.5
I have two database tables: "patent" and "fts". "fts" is a lookup table that contains attributes "id" and "val". The relation between "patent" and "fts" is many-to-many, and is realized by the table "patent_fts" which contains the foreign keys "patent_id" and "fts_id". Entity classes generated by Hibernate for "patent" and "fts" looks like the following:
Patent:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "patent", catalog = "patscoredb")
    public class Patent implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Set<Fts> ftses = new HashSet<Fts>(0);
    // other attributes...


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "patent_fts", catalog = "patscoredb", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "patent_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fts_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Fts> getFtses() {
        return this.ftses;
    }
    // other methods...
    }
```

Fts:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fts", catalog = "patscoredb")
public class Fts implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer ftsId;
private String val;
private Set<Patent> patents = new HashSet<Patent>(0);
// other attributes...

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ftses")
public Set<Patent> getPatents() {
    return this.patents;
}
// other methods...
}
```

What I want to do is to create submit form that contains an HTML table that lists all patents. Each row in the table should have a multiple select that contains all possible fts values. The user will use that dropdown list to assign one (or more fts) to each patent. When the user submits the form, there should be corresponding entries relating patents to ftses in the many-to-many table "patent_fts".
Here is my view:

```
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
      </head>
    <body>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/patscore/maintaindata/editpatentscorrelation" id="submit-form" modelAttribute="patentWrapper">
          <div id="page-wrapper">
             <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table id="patents" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th class="header">Internal Number<i class="fa "></i></th>
                        <th class="header">Correlating Field of Technical Solution <i class="fa "></i></th>
                        <th class="header">Title <i class="fa "></i></th>
                        <th class="header">Short Description <i class="fa "></i></th>
                        <th class="header">Picture <i class="fa "></i></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                     <c:forEach var="patent" items="${patentWrapper.patentList}" varStatus="i">
                      <tr>
                            <td>${patent.caseReference}</td>
                            <td>
                                <form:select id="multiselect_id_${i.index}" multiple="true" path="patentList[${i.index}].ftses">
                                    <c:forEach items="${ftsList}" var="fts">
                                        <c:set var="isSelected" value="false" />
                                        <c:forEach items="${patentWrapper.patentList[i.index].ftses}" var="patentFts">
                                            <c:if test="${patentFts.ftsId==fts.ftsId}">
                                                <c:set var="isSelected" value="true" />
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${isSelected}">
                                                <option value="${fts.ftsId}" label="${fts.val}" selected="selected"></option>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <option value="${fts.ftsId}" label="${fts.val}"></option>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </form:select>
                            </td>
                            <td>${patent.internalTitle}</td>
                            <td>${patent.abstract_}</td>
                            <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
             </div>

            </div>
    </form:form> 
    <script src="../resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("select[id^='multiselect_id_']").multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
                });
            });
        </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

You cannot use a list as a model attribute for the form, so I created a wrapper class for the list of patents called PatentWrapper:

```
public class PatentWrapper {
    private List<Patent> patentList;

    public PatentWrapper(){

    }

    public PatentWrapper(List<Patent> patentList){
        this.patentList = patentList;
    }

    public void addPatent(Patent p){
        patentList.add(p);
    }

    public void removePatent(Patent p){
        patentList.add(p);
    }

    public void removePatent(int index){
        patentList.remove(index);
    }

    public List<Patent> getPatentList() {
        return patentList;
    }

    public void setPatentList(List<Patent> patentList) {
        this.patentList = patentList;
    }
}
```

My controller looks like the following:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "patentWrapper" })
public class CorrelationController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CorrelationController.class);
    @Autowired
    private PatentHome patentDao;
    @Autowired
    private FtsHome ftsDao;

/* Supplying the view with the list of patents and the list of ftses */
@RequestMapping(value = "/maintaindata/correlationpatent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createCorrelationPatent(Locale locale, Model model) {
        List<Patent> patList = patentDao.findAllWithFtses();
        List<Fts> ftsList = ftsDao.findAll();

        PatentWrapper patentWrapper = new PatentWrapper(patList);
        model.addAttribute("patentWrapper", patentWrapper);
        model.addAttribute("ftsList", ftsList);
        return "maintaindata/correlation-patent";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/maintaindata/editpatentscorrelation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editPatents(
            @ModelAttribute("patentWrapper") PatentWrapper patentWrapper,
            Locale locale) {

        List<Patent> patentList = patentWrapper.getPatentList();
        for (Patent patent : patentList) {
            patentDao.attachDirty(patent);
        }
        return "redirect:../";
    }

@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "ftses",
                new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class) {
                    @Override
                    protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                        String ftsId = (String) element;
                        Fts fts = ftsDao.findById(Integer.parseInt(ftsId));
                        return fts;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

The data is correctly loaded into the html table, but the submit doesn't work properly.
**First problem:** 
Let's say we have a list of 14 ftses in table fts, and user assigned patent 1 with fts 5. What happens is that a new fts is created in table fts with id 15 and value 5 (the value is the correct fts id!!). then an entry in table patent_fts is created with patent_id = 1, and fts_id = 15.
**Second problem:**
if user reloads the table, and assigns another fts (say fts 6) to the same patent 5, the old entry in table patent_fts (patent_id 1 fts_id 15) is overwritten with fts_id 16!
I am sure I am doing it wrong, but since I am fairly new to spring, I really don't understand what causes that behavior.
 
I will appreciate your help.